# Controlling nesting level in vue draggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In:

https://codesandbox.io/s/djch5?file=/src/components/NestedDraggable.vue

nesting is controlled through directives (`v-if`):

```
<template> 
  <draggable class="dragArea" tag="ul" :list="tasks" :group="{ name: 'g1' }">
    <li v-for="el in tasks" :key="el.name">
      <generic-item :taskItem="el"> </generic-item>
      <p>{{ el.name }}</p>
      <div v-if="el.type === 'inventoryCategory'">
        <nested-draggable :tasks="el.tasks" />
      </div>      
    </li>
  </draggable>
</template>
```

and it works as recursion stops at the category level (a section includes a category, and a category, none or more items).

The issue is that sections can be dragged into one another. How can I avoid this? (a section may only contain items).

Currently, type inference is done by checking a field (`"type": "inventoryCategory"`) against possible values and rendering tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flbdx

(nesting is managed in:

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wright-6lhk6?file=/src/components/NestedDraggable.vue

```
checkMove: function (evt) {
  // no items outside a category
  if (itemElem.type === "inventoryItem") {
    if (evt.to.childNodes.length > 0) {
      var k = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < evt.to.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        if (
          evt.to.childNodes[i].getAttribute("element-type") ===
          "inventoryCategory"
        ) {
          k++;
        }
      }
      if (k === evt.to.childNodes.length) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // No nested categories
  if (evt.from !== evt.to && itemElem.type === "inventoryCategory") {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
},
```

)